# panda3d - key.accept does funny things

Tags: key, panda3d

I am using panda3d for a game, however, I am having some difficulties with accept:

```
 def acceptKeys(self):



    base.accept("arrowLeft", self.setKeys, ["arrowLeft",1])
    base.accept("arrowRight", self.setKeys, ["arrowRight",1])
    base.accept("arrowUp", self.setKeys, ["arrowUp",1])
    base.accept("arrowDown", self.setKeys, ["arrowDown",1])
    base.accept("space", self.setKeys, ["space",1])
```

The thing is, it works absolutely fine for space.
It does NOT work for any of the othe keys, and I have tried it with charakter keys (such as w a s d), too!

Just nothing seems to happen when a key is pressed.

I did use the keynames that are given in the manual for panda3d.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual](https://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Keyboard_Support) states that you should use:

```
   arrow_left
   arrow_right
   arrow_up
   arrow_down
```

Maybe it's that simple?

Comment: It WAS that simple. So sorry. I am heartily ashamed of that -.- Look, I would LOVE to vote you up, but as yet I have no reputation, so I just accept your answer.